# how to implement TxDataAvailable. how to know the size of buffer to be sent to USB layer

Tags: serial-port, macos-big-sur, userspace, driverkit

I want to develop a serial driver using a driver kit framework.I am trying to override IOUserserial class methods.But i don't know how to get the size of buffer to be sent to USB layer using TXDataAvailable() and RXDataAvailable() functions? Any reference code will be helpful.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Why are you writing a serial driver? Do you have a USB-to-serial chip with a custom protocol? Or is it more a learning project?

Comment: Actually we have some requirement to handle in the driver.

Comment: So in other words: you don't want to tell.

Comment: I am sorry I doesn't mean that I am developing a customized protocol